# undefined reference to `_WinMain@16' with cygwin and mingw in openssl

Tags: cygwin, openssl, mingw, winmain

I kind of am struggling with OpenSSL over here. I downloaded the current release 1.0.1 and the compilation itself works. I can even call ./apps/openssl.exe. But when I get to the linking process the linker complains:

```
/usr/i686-pc-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/libmingw32.a(main.o): In function `main':
/usr/src/mingw-runtime/mingw-runtime-3.20-1/src/mingwrt-3.20-mingw32/main.c:73: undefined reference to `_WinMain@16'
```

(this is if I use mingw in cygwin, the same error occurs with cygwin itself)
This is the cygwin error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../libcygwin.a(libcmain.o):(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `_WinMain@16'
```

Now I found out that this means that it doesn't find a main function, but this couldn't actually be, can it? I mean openssl HAS its main-function. And concerning mingw: I can't find that file it mentions so there could be cause of the error, but libcygwin.a does exist (though I have no idea how to figure out if it has a main function).

So basically I ask: Why does this error occur that only occurs if I don't add a main function. Did I miss something?

Edit: Sorry to have missed that: I am on Win 7 x64 Enterprise

Comment: I think you're cutting off too much of the error log. Say `make` again and put what you get on pastebin.com or similar. Don't `make clean`, just tell it to retry the last steps before it failed again.

Comment: I did actually skip the problem so I do not struggle with it any more. Thanks for your comment (which I actually didn't see even though I checked back here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this for a solution](http://www.mail-archive.com/mingw-w64-public@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01519.html).  Steps summarized below:

1. unpack the .tar with the `msys tools` and **NOT** 7-zip.
2. Use `tar -xzf openssl-x.y.z.tar` where x.y.z denotes your version.
3. Then run the commands and it will work like a charm.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.